# Call JavaScript function from ASP.net code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, pageload

I’m trying to call a JavaScript function from Code behind but no luck so far. I tried to add the following snippets inside `Page_Load` method.

I’ve tried as below

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "foo", "alert('test22222')", true);
```

Also as below

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Type.GetType("System.String"), "addScript", "alert('test22222');", true);
```

None worked for me. Is there anything I’m missing here? I would like to show the alert message before loading the page.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "before loading the page"?

Comment: before rendering the page perhaps?

Comment: RegisterstartupScript will put the Javascript at the very end of the page, so the rendering will have completed (I think) before it's executed. You may better off just including the code in your ASPX page, somewhere near the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can implement it in page_prerender event

```
    protected void page_prerender( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
         your code here;
}
```

Comment: This behaves same as the current one :(

Comment: I want to call a function before the page renders in the screen. So I tried to implement it. It didn't get called. I even called alert as given in the code that also didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a ; in you code. Try this it worked for me.

But i would suggest the `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` over the `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` as the first one is designed for AJAX calls. Which will work for even partial page post backs.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "foo", "alert('test22222');", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work. You forgot semicolon at end of your alert:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "foo", "alert('test22222');", true);
```

Comment: It has no effect :( same behavior